# Strange space behavior of Haskell program

Tags: performance, haskell

I thought that the `Cont` monad is just equivalent to CPS Transformation, so if I have 
a monadic sum, if I run in the `Identity` monad, it will fail due to stack overflow, and if
I run it in the `Cont` Monad, it will be okay due to tail recursion.

So I've written a simple program to verify my idea. But to my surprise, the result is unreasonable due to my limited knowledge.

All programs are compiled using `ghc --make Test.hs -o test && ./test`

```
sum0 n = if n==0  then  0  else n + sum0 (n-1)
sum1 n = if  n==0  then return 0 else sum1 (n-1) >>= \ v ->  seq v (return (n+v))
sum2 n k = if n == 0 then k 0 else sum2 n (\v -> k (n + v))
sum3 n k = if n == 0 then k 0 else sum3 n (\ !v -> k (n + v))
sum4 n k = if n == 0 then k 0 else sum4 n (\ v -> seq v ( k (n + v)))
sum5 n = if  n==0  then return 0 else sum5 (n-1) >>= \ v ->   (return (n+v))
```

- `main = print (sum0 3000000)`
  Stack overflow. This is reasonable.
- `main = print (flip runCont id (sum1 3000000))`
  Uses 180M memory, which is reasonable, but I am not clear why `seq` needed here, since its continuation is not applied until `n` goes to 0.
- `main = print (flip runCont id (sum5 3000000))`
  Stack overflow. Why?
- `main = print (flip runCont (const 0) (sum1 3000000))`
  Uses 130M memory. This is reasonable.
- `main = print (flip runCont (const 0) (sum5 3000000))`
  Uses 118M memory. This is reasonable.
- `main = print (sum2 3000000 (const 0))`
  Uses a lot of memory (more than 1G). I thought `sum2` is equivalent to `sum5` (when `sum5` is in `Cont` monad). Why?
- `main = print (sum3 3000000 (const 0))`
  Uses a lot of memory. I thought `sum3` is equivalent to `sum1` (`Cont` monad). Why?
- `main = print (runIdentity (sum1 3000000))`
  Stack overflow, exactly what I want.
- `main = print (sum3 3000000 id)`
  Uses a lot of memory. Equivalent to `sum1`, why?
- `main = print (sum4 3000000 id)`
  Uses a lot of memory. Equivalent to sum1, why?
- `main = print (sum [1 .. 3000000])`
  Stack overflow. The source of `sum = foldl (+) 0`, so this is reasonable.
- `main = print (foldl' (+) 0 [1 .. 3000000])`
  Uses 1.5M.

Comment: Note that in most cases, when considering performance issues in Haskell, you should compile with optimizations enabled. A lot of seemingly obvious things actually rely on tiny little optimizations, which GHC won't apply if you don't tell it to.

Comment: I have a typo for sum2,sum3,sum4, the only strange behavior is what makes sum1 and sum5 different, and why (flip runCont id (sum5 3000000)) stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it looks to me like `sum2`, `sum3`, and `sum4` never actually decrement `n`. So they're using lots of memory because they're going into an infinite loop that does allocation.

After correcting that, I've run each of your tests again with the following results, where "allocation" refers to approximate peak memory use:

- `main = print (sum0 3000000)` : Stack overflow, after allocating very little memory
- `main = print (flip runCont id (sum1 3000000))` : Success, allocating similar amounts to what you saw
- `main = print (flip runCont id (sum5 3000000))` : Stack overflow, after allocating similar amounts of memory as `sum1`.
- `main = print (flip runCont (const 0) (sum1 3000000))` : Success, similar allocation as the above
- `main = print (flip runCont (const 0) (sum5 3000000))` : Same
- `main = print (sum2 3000000 (const 0))` : Success, about 70% as much allocation as `sum1`
- `main = print (sum3 3000000 (const 0))` : Success, about 50% as much allocation as `sum1`
- `main = print (runIdentity (sum1 3000000))` : Stack overflow, with little allocation
- `main = print (sum3 3000000 id)` : Success, about 50% as much allocation as `sum1`
- `main = print (sum4 3000000 id)` : Success, about 50% as much allocation as `sum1`
- `main = print (sum [1 .. 3000000])` : Stack overflow, with about 80% as much allocation as `sum1`
- `main = print (foldl' (+) 0 [1 .. 3000000])` : Success, with almost no allocation

So that's mostly what you expected, with the exception of why `seq` makes such a difference between `sum1` vs. `sum5`.

Comment: Thanks, I have a typo for sum2, sum3, sum4. So that's mostly what I expected as you said. But I am still not clear what makes sum1 different from sum5, and why (flip runCont id (sum5 3000000)) stackoverflow?

Comment: @bobzhang: I don't know off the top of my head, nor did very brief profiling enlighten me, and unfortunately I don't have time to look into it more deeply right now.

Comment: both (flip runCont id (sum5 3000000)) and (runIdentity (sum5 3000000)) stackoverflow, but they are for different reasons. The first is due to the laziness of return which results in a big code thunk. The latter is due to non-tail-recursion. Thank you for all :-)

Comment: @bobzhang: Really? That was my first thought, but given that both `Identity` and `ContT` are newtypes and the structure of the expression I couldn't immediately see how that would cause a problem here. But as I said, I didn't have time to look at it thoroughly. But yes, in general `return` is lazy and that is absolutely something to keep in mind. Either way, glad you figured it out, sorry I wasn't more help. :]